# R Multiple Linear Regression; plotting results

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do some exploratory analysis on some weather. I'd like to do a multiple linear regression on my data and then plot the predicted value against the actual value. Here's where I've got so far:

```
data<-read.csv("Amsterdam.csv", header=TRUE)
data2<-data[SolarAltitude>0,]
data2.lm<-lm(DirectRadiation ~ DryBulbTemperature + RelHum
   +AtmosphericPressure, data=data2)
data.data.frame(data2,fitted.value=fitted(data2.lm),residual=resid(data2.lm))
```

If you could help, I would be very grateful,

Comment: With just one response variable, your method is multiple rather than multivariate. Indeed, using several predictors is hardly a big deal now, and many people would drop the multiple, not that "multiple" is in any sense wrong. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Physically, your regression doesn't make sense. Direct radiation is an external input. The other variables are state variables saying something about the atmosphere at ground level. The physics here doesn't reduce to linear relations any way.

Comment: Direct radiation at the top of the atmosphere, yes, but it gets more complicated as to how much of it gets to the surface. I agree it's a long shot, but I'm trying to use this estimate data I don't have and I'm trying to make something that might be better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fitted` returns the fitted (predicted) values. To plot the fitted values against the actual values, you can use:

```
plot(data2$DirectRadiation, fitted(data2.lm))
```

This will produce a plot with the actual values on the horizontal axis and the fitted values on the vertical axis.

If the above code doesn't work due to missing data, you can try one of the following approaches:

```
 plot(fitted(data2.lm) + residuals(data2.lm), fitted(data2.lm))

 plot(data2.lm$model[[1]], fitted(data2.lm))
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, > nrow(data2)
[1] 4407
> plot(data$DirectRadiation,fitted(data2.lm)
+ )
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
> nrow(fitted(data2.lm))
NULL

Comment: Do you have missing data?

Comment: @James See the update of my answer.